# Format Phone # into 10 Digits / Remove extra characters

Tags: javascript, html, forms, trim

I need to have a phone number be formatted on the fly into a 10 digit number - remove ALL spaces, dashes, dots, etc.

EX: (123) 321-1234 / 123-321-1234 becomes 1233211234

I've seen examples of doing the opposite, but since I'm new to Javascript, I don't know how to do it.

Ideally, formatting should while the number is being entered into text field, or when a Submit button is pressed.

PS - I only know HTML, so please provide code for both  and  tags.

Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey Levchik- Welcome to Stackoverflow! Usually it's best practice to provide some sort of example of what you've tried. Just saying "please give me code" is kind of frowned upon. We want to be here when you get stuck, not when you want other people to do your work for you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex to remove all non-digits from the textbox's value. Here's an example:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
```

With this JS:

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
}

addEvent(window, "load", function () {
    addEvent(document.getElementById("text1"), "change", function () {
        var tel = this.value;
        tel = tel.replace(/\D+/g, "");
        this.value = tel;
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6vC3x/

The replacing happens when the value of the textbox is changed (by user input) and the textbox is blurred (unselected).

The whole `addEvent` function stuff is just to hopefully reliably add event handlers to an element across browsers consistently.

Comment: @LevchikB No problem, glad it helped! You might want to accept the answer, or explain any other help you need specifically with this

Comment: Ian, one more question about this.

If user enters country code before the number, can we drop the first DIGIT if it is 1 or 0 (zero). How would you go about it?

Ex: 1-234-567-1234 becomes 2345671234

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LevchikB Sorry for such a delayed response. So for that, the easiest way I could think of is to use this: `tel = tel.replace(/\D+/g, "").replace(/^[01]/, "");`. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6vC3x/1/ . I hope it helps!

Comment: hey man - I was just going to ask same question about country code (1 before number) but saw your last comment - thats a bunch!! your little script has been doing miracles for me all these years!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just replace all non numeric digits characters with empty string.

```
("(123) 321-1234").replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect solution but will work. Use split if you need to extract a number before some character appearance like '/' from the string and then using regex \D to remove non-digit characters from a string and then mapped the numbers in a required format in the below example US Tel Format.

```
`let rawString = "111.222.3333 / need to remove this text (some more text)"

 const formatTelNumber = (phoneNumberString) => {
   let stringWithNumber = phoneNumberString.split("/")[0]
   let cleaned = ("" + stringWithNumber).replace(/\D/g, "")
   let match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
   if (match) {
     return `(${match[1]}) ${match[2]}-${match[3]}`
   }
   return null;
};
console.log(formatTelNumber(rawString))`
```

Cheers! JK